# Getting 'int' object is not iterable while trying to solve for x

Tags: python

I am trying to solve where `x = -57.8`. I am new to coding, so I do not know where I am going wrong in this code. I am constantly facing either object not iterable. I have not been able to figure out why!

```
import math
realNumber = input("Enter a floating-point real number:")
number =int(float(realNumber))

def f(x):
    for x in number:
        if x<5:
            print("The value of x is:",(x**2/(math.fabs(x)+2))**2)
        elif x==5:
            print("The value of x is:",equal=(x**2/math.fabs(x)+2))
        else:
            print("The value of x is:",math.sqrt(x**2/(math.fabs(x)+2)))
            return(x)
        print(f("-57.8"))
f("-57.8")
```

Comment: Well you're doing `for x in number` where `number` is an int... What do you expect that to do?

Comment: `for x in range(number)` ?

Comment: Also doing `for x in number` overrides the value of the passed argument which makes it useless...

Comment: What is this code supposed to be doing?

Comment: The code is supposed to be checking whether a number is greater, equal or less than 5. I am supposed to write a program that allows a user to enter a floating-point real number. Where, for example, if they enter x= -57.8, f(x) would be 3212

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem here is that many lines of your function have no reason to be there and act at direct cross-purposes to what you're trying to do.  Don't use a `for` loop if you don't mean to iterate, don't convert to `int` when you're supposed to be operating on a `float`, and above all else, don't enter random lines of code when you're trying to solve a problem; they will almost never help, and they will usually just break your program.

Here is a version of the code that I think accomplishes what you're trying to do.  The function `f` computes the value and returns it (using `return`) rather than printing it inside the function -- this makes it a pure mathematical function (you put a number in, you get a number out).  You can then call that function in the context of a `print` statement to print the returned value.

```
import math

def f(x):
    if x < 5:
        return (x**2 / (math.fabs(x) + 2))**2
    elif x == 5:
        return x**2 / math.fabs(x) + 2
    else:
        return math.sqrt(x**2 / (math.fabs(x) + 2))

number = float(input("Enter a floating-point real number: "))
print("The value of f(x) is:", f(number))
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, I will work on cleaning up my codes, I have only been learning 2 weeks, so it is a bit difficult right now, but it's a work in progress! I suppose I add extra info because I am not really sure/uncertain of how to write it! But this was most helpful!

Comment: The main thing is to start by thinking about what you want to do, step by step, and *then* figure out the exact line of code that will do each step, one at a time.  Break the big problem down into lots of smaller, easier problems -- this is the core of programming!  If you get stuck on a particular step, then you have a small specific problem that you can look up solutions for, vs just having a big mess of broken code that you don't know how to untangle.  If you don't understand the big problem well enough to break it into steps, there's no point writing code for it yet.  Draw pictures, etc!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import math
realNumber = input("Enter a floating-point real number:")

# Here you are converting string {ex: "2.5"} to float {ex: 2.5}  then to int {ex: 2}
# You can directly cast string to int if it is possible

#number =int(float(realNumber))
number =int(realNumber)

def f(x):
    #for x in number:
    # x is a number {ex: 5}, you can not loop over it, so this line not required
    if x<5:
        print("The value of x is:",(x**2/(math.fabs(x)+2))**2)
    elif x==5:
        print("The value of x is:",equal=(x**2/math.fabs(x)+2))
    else:
        print("The value of x is:",math.sqrt(x**2/(math.fabs(x)+2)))
        return(x)
        # After return statement no code gets executed
        # So this line not required
        # Also it is calling the function itself, which is {recursion}, it can lead to infinite loop
        #print(f("-57.8"))
        
#f("-57.8")
# you want to pass number
f(number)
```